# excel vba copy data to top most row of excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have queried a excel using ADODB and have a set of data which should be copied to the second worksheet, but when ever i try to insert data it always sits on the 2nd row ignoring the 1st one. I think this is because the 1st row is always treated as header. Are there any ways to insert data into the excel by creating 1st row as header and subsequently with values(with respect to the code i have written below).

```
Exceldb = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\VAS_AUTOMATION_v1.1\Book1.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
Dim sDBConnectionString, i, iCol

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
sDBConnectionString = Exceldb
con.ConnectionString = sDBConnectionString
con.Open

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    For i = 1 to 4
        Err.Clear
        wait 5
        con.Open
        If  Err.Number = 0 Then
            msgbox "opened"
        End If
    Next
else
    msgbox "opened"
End If

strROW = "UNIXOPERATIONS_16"
strROWID = "'" & strROW  & "'"

strQuery = "INSERT INTO [Sheet3$A1:A1] (" & strROWID1 & ") Values(" & strROWID & ")"

Set strRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Dim objCmd 'As New ADODB.Command
Set objCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objCmd.ActiveConnection = con
objCmd.CommandType = 1
objCmd.CommandText = strQuery
Set strRecordSet = objCmd.Execute

con.Close
```

Comment: I *believe* you would need to insert the values of the header on 1 executed query and then your actual values on the second.  `strQuery = "INSERT INTO [Sheet3$A1:A1] (" & strROWID1 & ") Values('Header_Text_Here)"`

Comment: I have tried this but it throws an error saying "The INSERT INTO statement contains unknown field name". It is a blank work sheet i am copying the data into.

Comment: That makes sense.  I would simple delete the 1st row. `Range("Sheet3!1:1").Delete`

Comment: Even though that serves the purpose. Once after deleting, will the 1st row act as a header(which was previously 2nd)?